# Powershell query custom column issue

Tags: powershell

I have below Powershell script which is missing something which I don't know.
Please help to resolve this.

```
Get-BrokerDesktopGroup | Select Name,@{Name = 'MaintMode'; Expression = {(Get-BrokerDesktop -MaxRecordCount 1000 -Filter {(DesktopGroupName -eq '$($_.Name)') -and (InMaintenanceMode -eq 'True')} | Select HostedMachineName).count}} | ft -AutoSize
```

The first column output is correct but the second column remains always zero.

Comment: Try to run the `expression` statement on its own to see if it does what you expect (of course replace `$($_.Name)` by a constant for this to work).

Comment: Needs to be double quotes around the variable or seems like they could be removed altogether. “$($_.name)” or just $_.name

Comment: If I look [here](https://developer-docs.citrix.com/projects/citrix-virtual-apps-desktops-sdk/en/latest/Broker/about_Broker_Filtering/#examples), `-Filter` should be a string, not a scriptblock

Comment: @zett42, I already tried that and expression statement works.

Comment: @DougMaurer, I have tried that too.

Comment: @Theo, I will try it and let you know. This could possibly be the solution. I'll be back with the status.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by [@Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo), I put the `-Filter` arguments inside double inverted commas instead of curly braces and my issue got resolved.